FlatList Android doesn't work when width < window.width
Everything works fine on iOS and even Android when the flatList.width exceeds window.width but it stutters and doesn't scroll smoothly when the flatList.width is smaller than the window.
I put together this quick example: Expo Snack
On my actuall app I disabled scrolling on Android when flatList.width < window.width but surely there's a better way?

Is it still not working? Maybe my answer help you with this problem. Check it!

This happens because the content container does not fill the FlatList size. You can add a style with flexGrow: 1 to the content container with the prop contentContainerStyle from ScrollView.
export default function App() {
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <View>
        <FlatList
          data={data}
          horizontal
          contentContainerStyle={styles.contentContainerStyle}
          showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
          renderItem={() => <AssetExample />}
          keyExtractor={(item) => item}
        />
      </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    padding: 8,
  },
  contentContainerStyle: {
    backgroundColor: 'green',
    // Remove or comment the next line to see the content container does not fill the FlatList size.
    flexGrow: 1,
  }
});

I cloned your Expo Snack and modified it. You can see it working on this Expo Snack.
